# Cards not centered in paper - Material-ui React App

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to center some dynamically generated cards in a paper using Material-ui, but something is doing so that they are always sticking to the left part of the paper. I used Inspect Element to see what it looks like exactly, and it seems that the Grid that contains each card is actually wider in the right part, and I don't know what is causing this.

```
// useStyles

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        maxWidth: "12vw",
        marginTop: '0.9vw',
        marginLeft: '0.9vw',
        marginBottom: '0.9vw',
        marginRight: '0'
    },
        media: {
        height: 0,
        paddingTop: '150%',
        objectFit: 'cover',
    },
    body: {
        alignSelf: 'end',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    actions: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        fullWidth: true
    },
    customWidth: {
        maxWidth: 500,
      },
});
```

and this is the main grid with everything

```
<Grid container>

    <Paper style={{ margin: "auto", width: 'auto', padding: '0', background: '#221211', overflow:'auto', maxWidth:'100%', textAlign: 'center' }} elevation={0}>
                    
    <Grid container justify="space-between" style={{ background:"transparent" }}>

        { data.map( (carte, index) => (
                
            <Grid xs={3} key={index}>
                        
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                    <Link to = {{ pathname:'/view-book', state: { data: data[index] } }} className={classes.actions} color="primary">
                        <CardActionArea style={{ maxWidth:"12vw" }}>
                            <CardMedia className={classes.media} fullWidth image={data[index].cover} title={data[index].title}></CardMedia>
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography noWrap gutterBottom color="textPrimary" variant='body1' component="h2">
                                    {data[index].title}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography noWrap variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p" style={{ marginBottom:'0px' }}>
                                    {data[index].description}
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                        </CardActionArea>
                    </Link>
                        <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
                            <Button style={{ fontSize: "0.7vw" }}  startIcon={<AddShoppingCart />} aria-label="wishlist" color="primary" variant="outlined">adaugă în wishlist</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                        
                </Card>
                        
            </Grid>
                    
        ))
        }

    </Grid>

    </Paper>

</Grid>
```

[This is how it looks when I check it with Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqnxe.png)

Everything except the Link component is imported from Material-ui.

Comment: Hi! Can you reproduce the problem online in codesandbox pls?

Comment: Hello @alisasani ! This should be it https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-ishizaka-ppgt7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this style

```
display: "flex",
justifyContent: "center"
```

to Grid component as below:

```
<Grid
          container
          justify="space-between"
          style={{
            background: "transparent",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
        >
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bush-ljl07?file=/src/App.js:1389-1625)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it looks like it is the same, I have tried with flex, but it's the same unfortunately https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-rain-9lrmh

Comment: finally solved it, looks like the card itself wasn't centered in the grid, that's what made it choose by default 0 as margin https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-rain-9lrmh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: well you should add to to the next `Grid` components. Please check this link (https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-cdn-74emd?file=/src/App.js) . I stored these styles in the `useStyles` and applied them by `className={classes.center}` in those four `Grid` components